# How to use case expression and min() with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, min, sql-null

The following query when I that execute

```
SELECT St.FirstName,St.LastName,
       CASE
         WHEN St.ISPackage='N' THEN Min(St.VisitingDate)
         WHEN St.ISPackage='Y' THEN St.VisitingDate
       END AS VisitingDate
  FROM SalesTransaction As St
  (...inner join and where clause)
  GROUP BY St.FirstName,St.LastName, St.VisitingDate
```

If I use St.VisitingDate in `Group By` the result is duplicated.

If not used St.VisitingDate in `Group By` show error

> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't have both St.VisitingDate and Min(St.VisitingDate). GROUP BY issue, not case expression issue.

Comment: Perhaps you actually want a windowed `MIN` and no `GROUP BY`? Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie Please be careful. Having 13 comments removed for lacking decorum is probably not what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can find an example of a better way to make your point. Maybe somewhere not so far away...

Answer (score 3):

I *suspect* that you want to group by name and get the visit date when `ISPackage` is "Y", and fallback on the earliest visit date if there is no date where `ISPackage` is "Y".

If so, you can do:

```
SELECT St.FirstName,St.LastName,
    COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN St.ISPackage = 'Y' THEN St.VisitingDate END), MIN(St.VisitingDate)) VisitingDate
FROM SalesTransaction As St
-- (...inner join and where clause)
GROUP BY St.FirstName,St.LastName
```

Comment: Thank you, Kindly give solution for below query

       CASE
         WHEN St.ISPackage='N' THEN Min(St.VisitingDate)
         WHEN St.ISPackage='Y' THEN St.VisitingDate
       END AS VisitingDate

Answer (score 0):

you can use below SQL-
I calculated min date using a subquery.

```
SELECT St.FirstName,St.LastName,
       CASE
         WHEN St.ISPackage='Y' THEN St.VisitingDate
         ELSE min_dt.min_VisitingDate
       END AS VisitingDate
  FROM 
  SalesTransaction As St
  (...inner join and where clause)
left join (select St.FirstName,St.LastName, min(St.VisitingDate) min_VisitingDate from SalesTransaction group by St.FirstName,St.LastName) min_dt 
ON St.FirstName =min_dt.FirstName ,St.LastName =min_dt.LastName
```